# Is there any way in Powershell to find ADF slices that completed in last 1 hour for example?

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory

Given certain dataset, I want to find out how many of its slices actually became Ready in last 1 hour (or say 2 hours, it's just an example). This gives me idea of cluster health. Because out of dozens of datasets, if no Ready slice was produced in last couple of hours, it's surely alarming for me.

I know Powershell has a cmdlet to get slice status which returns actual start and end time of slices -- but the problem is it finds that only on the basis of slice information. I don't care if the slice date is 1 year back -- I want the status on the basis of actual start and end time for that slice -- and I want to do it programmatically.

Worst case is -- one will need to get status for all possible slices and then get actual start and end time, but this is very inefficient -- there is also limit on how many API calls one can in an hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the cmdlet your looking for here is **Get-AzureRmDataFactoryActivityWindow** this accepts a run window and will return the result of a time slice either Ready, Waiting, Failed etc.

Example of use:

```
Get-AzureRmDataFactoryActivityWindow `
    -DataFactoryName $ADFName.DataFactoryName `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
    | ? {$_.WindowStart -ge $Now} `
    | SELECT ActivityName, ActivityType, WindowState, RunStart, InputDatasets, OutputDatasets `
    | Sort-Object ActivityName
```

Use this with the required params to return a list of the information you want. I might then stick it into a SQL table for wider monitoring etc. But you could use an array in PowerShell to get the count value and produce the alert. Next wrap it up in something that polls on the hour maybe.

Here's a link to all ADF PowerShell cmdlets available in the Azure module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactories/?view=azurermps-4.0.0

Hope this helps

Comment: Tried using it, I get the error -- The term 'Get-​Azure​Rm​Data​Factory​Activity​Window' is not recognized as the name of a  cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. As per the MS documentation this cmdlet exists in the module Azure​RM.​Data​Factories , but don't know how to get it. My PS editor detects as I type this cmdlet, still throws the error.

Comment: It seems I do have the module AzureRM.DataFactories -- but this particular cmdlet is not part of the local installation of the module. How to get the latest module?

Comment: Yeah, there have been many releases of it. Search for the Azure SDK and install the PowerShell extensions.